# iMovie with Audio USB Interface

Tags: audio-recording, software, audio-interfaces, usb

I am using iMovie for recording audio during a Lecture (I nees to see video during recording) with a M-Audio M-Track interface (two XLR microphone).

The thing is that I can only record first microhone, because I can-t select the interface BUS on iMovie (or I didn't see it).

I also tested record with a XENYX UFX1204 (12 inputs), but I can only record from first input to.

Can anybody please help me?

Grateful

MacBook, iOS 9.2.1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an imovie support question.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to select your input/output devices on both the system settings and iMovie Preferences if you want to record. I would suggest using Garage Band that way you can have two audio tracks. You can import the video in iMovie and watch along with it as you play it back and record. Then, export to iMovie.